# Has anyone found a way to turn the color GCC warnings/errors off?

Tags: gcc

GCC now colors its warnings/errors. This is a horrible misfeature that
I have not found out how to turn off. Doing -fno-diagnostics-color does not get it. The colors interact with my terminal colors and result in a completely unreadable MESS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler is free software. You are allowed to improve it.

Comment: Seems to work on my system (9.3.0, 10.1.0, 8.3.0, 7.4.0, all on Gentoo x86_64).  What's your environment?  And note it's possible to build gcc yourself and have color diagnostics off by default.

Comment: I'd been using `-fdiagnostics-color=never` in a wrapper script. But, needed to do it for a project that I couldn't control. I searched and found this page and: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html From _that_ page, we get: **Setting GCC_COLORS to the empty string disables colors.** Tried `export GCC_COLORS=""` and it works.

Comment: Please stop this kind of snarky responses, it is a perfectly reasonable question, and suggesting that people should recompile the compiler is just like saying "go find the answer yourself".

Answer (score 1):

According to [its documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html), `gcc` accepts the `-fno-diagnostics-color` option.

Since [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), you are allowed to improve it. Consider writing your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) (which could use on Linux [isatty(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) to disable coloring)

You can also try to redirect the compiler's output to some file.

On my Linux/Ubuntu 20.04/x86-64 box, compiling (with GCC 10.2) file `/tmp/err.c` below:

```
% cat /tmp/err.c
#error single line in /tmp/err.c
```

using

```
% gcc -Wall -c /tmp/err.c |& od -cx
```

does not emit any ANSI escape code related to colors (the colors are added by the SlackOverflow site), using [od(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html). And I am getting:

```
% gcc -c -O /tmp/err.c|& cat   
/tmp/err.c:1:2: error: #error single line in /tmp/error.c
     1 | #error single line in /tmp/error.c
       |  ^~~~~
```

without any colors. This with

```
 % gcc --version
 gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) 10.2.0
```

And the standard [cat(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) program (from [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) 8.30).

So you could redirect your build to some temporary file, like [GNU Autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) does.